# Создание пагинации Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

У меня есть два вывода пользовательских таблиц. Мне нужно выводить новых юзеров в первой колонке

Во втором колонке - по рейтингу и расположите в порядке убывания, а также сделайте разбивку на страницы

Вот что я сделал

```
public function __invoke()

    {

        $users = Server::take(2);

        $topUsers = Server::withCount('topServersUser')->

        orderBy('top_user_count','DESC')->get()->paginate(3);



        return view('main.index', compact('users', 'topUsers' ));

    }
```

Но она не работает и выдает ошибку
`Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.`

для `$user` мне нужно сделать вывод новых созданных участниках

а для `$topUsers` вывод идет по убыванию и по рейтингу. И сделайте ту же разбивку на страницы

Чтобы в итоге в index.blade.php я написал  `{{ $topUsers->links() }}` и была pagination

Помогите решить проблему, как ее реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `get()` и `paginate()` несовместимы. `get()` отдает массив коллекций уже. `paginate()` тоже отдает массив коллекций, но ограниченно по страницам. Когда Вы пытаетесь применять `paginate()` на `get()`, в этот момент уже нет методов модели, а только коллекции — появляется ошибка об отсутствии метода.

Поэтому если хотите получать страницы — пишите только `paginate()`:

```
public function __invoke()
{
    $users = Server::take(2);
    $topUsers = Server::withCount('topServersUser')
                ->orderBy('top_user_count','DESC')->paginate(3);

    return view('main.index', compact('users', 'topUsers' ));
}
```

Comment: Я сделал как вы написали и $users у меня не выводится почему-то

Comment: Все, я решил проблему $users = Server::take(2)->get(); 
Спасибо

Comment: @Yan Тогда отметьте ответ как решение)